# why does rails want to drop a table, just to rename a column (sqlite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a table ("players") on which another table depends (has a foreign key that refers to players table).

I want to change a column name in this first table.

Rails db:migrate tells me:

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP
>   TABLE "players"

While I suppose I could just remove the foreign key and try again; nowhere do I find that rails must drop a table to rename a column.

Comment: Because until a few months ago, to rename a column in sqlite you had to create a new table with the desired column names, copy everything to it, drop the original, and rename the new table. Usually you turn off foreign key enforcement while doing so.

Comment: So if sqlite just copies the table, does that mean one could merely drop the foreign key constraint, instead of the foreign key as I mentioned? (referential integrity remaining, given essentially same table recreated?)

Comment: You can add or drop foreign key constraints on columns with the same process, yes. The workflow is laid out in full here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html (there's also a simpler method for dropping foreign keys)